# Push empty element into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have PHP array called 'tags', which is being filled with objects that I get from the model. And I need to push one more element into this array, which should be an empty string. For now my code looks as follows:

```
$tags = [];
$tags  = compact(WebsiteTag::all());
array_push($tags, '');
return $tags;
```

And as a result I get an array where the only element is this empty string. The same happens if I try to push some actual string -- just this string remains in the array. I've tried also creating an array like:

```
$tags = [];
array_push($tags, compact(WebsiteTag::all()), '');
return $tags;
```

And

```
array_push($tags, WebsiteTag::all(), '');
```

And also

```
$tags = array(WebsiteTag::all(), '');
```

But in these cases I get an array of two elements, where the first one is an array with objects and the second one is my empty string.
Is it possible to create an array of different type elements? And if it is, how should I push them correctly?

Comment: try with $tags[] = '';

Comment: show `var_dump(compact(WebsiteTag::all()));`

Answer (score 3):

I cannot know for sure what `WebsiteTag::all()` returns but I think the result is an array of tags. So what I would do is one of these two options:

```
$tags = WebsiteTags::all();
$tags[] = '';

// Or
$tags = array_merge(WebsiteTags::all(), array(''));
```

Comment: @Oli By just a minute :D

Answer (score 3):

If  WebsiteTag::all() returns an array you could simply merge them together:

```
$tags = array_merge(WebsiteTag::all(), ['']);
```

See the documentation of [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for details

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it by doing as follows:

```
$website_tags = [];
$tags  = WebsiteTag::all();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    array_push($website_tags, $tag);
}
array_push($website_tags, '');
```